# How can i make the text not transparent in the context.fillText

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

```
context.font = '20pt Calibri';
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(225,225,225,0.5)';
var width = context.measureText(message2).width;
context.fillRect(xIndent, yIndent+100, width, 60);

context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,85,0,1.0)';
context.fillText(message3, xIndent, yIndent+100);
```

I want the `context.fillText` to have no transparency and the `context.fillRect` to have some transparency

For some reason, I can make both transparent or both opague

The result is both TEXT and Background color are of the same transparency

Comment: What are the results for this code?

Comment: both are the same transparency (0.5)

Comment: Have you set globalAlpha somewhere. Try putting `context.globalAlpha = 1` befor the code.

Comment: I can't re-produce your issue on FF43. Could you please create a fiddle, or a code snippet showing your issue.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce your issue, on Chrome 47

Comment: If the `globalAlpha` did not work try `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"` as some comp modes look similar to transparency. The code you presented has nothing wrong with it. There is also the possibility that the Canvas element CSS style has transparency set, so check that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset everything after the first text is written. Because you can set fillStyle after you have drawn or written something, it will still fill it. So, if you want to have to things drawn or written after each other you need to reset everything, so that the next fillStyle doesn't change it's fillStyle too. You need to use `context.beginPath()` after you have wriite the first text. Here is your code corrected :

```
context.font = '20pt Calibri';
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(225,225,225,0.5)';
var width = context.measureText(message2).width;
context.fillRect(xIndent, yIndent+100, width, 60);

context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,85,0,1.0)';
context.fillText(message3, xIndent, yIndent+100);
```

It is best to use `context.beginPath()` each time you want to draw or write something else.... I hope this helped.....